# Telegram разместить кнопки вертикально

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Сейчас всё работает, создается две кнопки находящиеся на одной линии. 
а как сделать их расположение вертикальным? т.е. одна кнопка в одной линии, 
друг под другом

```
# кнопки вызывающие действия
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def any_msg(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нажми меня", callback_data="test")
    callback_button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нажми меня2", callback_data="test2")
    keyboard.add(callback_button, callback_button2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я сообщение", reply_markup=keyboard)


# обработчик (кнопки вызывающие действия)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    # Если сообщение из чата с ботом
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "test":
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Пыщь")    

        elif call.data == "test2":
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Пыщь2")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.add` добавляет `row`, то есть Вам нужно делать `.add` несколько раз, чтобы получить несколько линий (`row`), например:

```
In [17]: import telebot as tb

In [18]: from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

In [19]: token = '<token>'

In [20]: bot = tb.TeleBot(token)

In [21]: @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    ...: def start(message):
    ...:     keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    ...:     first_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text='first', callback_data='first_cb')
    ...:     second_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text='second', callback_data='second_cb')
    ...:     keyboard.add(first_btn)
    ...:     keyboard.add(second_btn)
    ...:     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='hello', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

И небольшой совет по поводу обработки `callback`, чтобы не сваливать всё в одну функцию, используйте параметр `func` в декораторе `callback_query_handler`, например чтобы среагировать на `callback` вида `some_data`, нужно сделать следующее:

```
In [8]: @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'some_data')
   ...: def handle(call):
   ...:     ...
```

Как видим, эта функция отвечает только за обработку `callback'a` `some_data`, так можно поступить со всеми значениями `callback_data`.

Comment: спасибо, а как сделать так, что бы полсе нажатия на кнопку она не исчезала а поднималась вверх вместе с текстом?

Comment: @NormalArs что значит "поднималась вверх" ?

Comment: ну идет чат, я что то пишу, бот что то пишет, и старые сообщения уползают вверх экрана. я хочу сделать это и с кнопками

Comment: @NormalArs изменяйте сообщение, а не присылайте новое

Comment: это не всегда удобно)

Comment: @NormalArs По другому никак

Comment: а вы можете кодом поделиться для изменения сообщений?) может я просто что то не то написал

Comment: @NormalArs В вашем примере используется `edit_message_text`, это оно и есть

Comment: но он просто печатает текст

Comment: Тогда я не понял что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74697/discussion-between-alban-and-normalars).

Answer (score 2):

Клавиатуры - это массив массивов кнопок, то есть массив "строк" с кнопками - упрощённо говоря, один массив = одна строка. Сейчас там один массив, соответственно только одна строка. Чтобы получить кнопки "в столбик" разделите свой массив с кнопками на несколько массивов, содержащих по 1 кнопке.

Пока только так, пишу с телефона. Если будет не понятно потом отредактирую.

Comment: keyboard.add[[callback_button],[callback_button2]] ругается  'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: keyboard.add([[callback_button],[callback_button2]]) ругается  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dic'

Comment: keyboard.add([[callback_button],[callback_button2]].to_dict())  
 ругается  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'