# посмотрите код телеграм бота, мне кажется что я пишу костыли

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

мне кажется что что то пошло не так
при старте бота появляется 3 кнопки, а при создании подменю для этих кнопок я начинаю писать `if/elif` лесенкой, чем глубже лежит пункт меню - тем больше отступ
а туда внутрь уже не засунешь обработчик нажатий `def callback_inline(call)`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import time
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
bot = telebot.TeleBot('123456')

# Главное меню
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    keyboard     = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    book         = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Забронировать столик"   , callback_data="book")
    callwaiter   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Вызвать официанта"      , callback_data="callwaiter")
    makeorder    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Сделать заказ"          , callback_data="makeorder")
    keyboard.add(book)
    keyboard.add(callwaiter)
    keyboard.add(makeorder)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "доброе утро", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "book":
            keyboarddate     = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            date1        = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1 апреля"   , callback_data="date1")
            date2    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="2 апреля"       , callback_data="date2")
            date3    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="3 апреля"       , callback_data="date3")
            date4        = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="4 апреля"   , callback_data="date4")
            date5    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="5 апреля"       , callback_data="date5")
            date6    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="6 апреля"       , callback_data="date6")
            date7        = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="7 апреля"   , callback_data="date7")
            date8    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="8 апреля"       , callback_data="date8")
            date9    = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="9 апреля"       , callback_data="date9")
            keyboarddate.add(date1, date2, date3)
            keyboarddate.add(date4, date5, date6)
            keyboarddate.add(date7, date8, date9)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выберите дату визита", reply_markup=keyboarddate)


        elif call.data == "callwaiter":
            keyboardwaiter   = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            passwaiter   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пароль введен"          , callback_data="passwaiter")
            keyboardwaiter.add(passwaiter)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "пожалуйста введите пароль", reply_markup=keyboardwaiter)


        elif call.data == "makeorder":
            keyboardorder    = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            odate1       = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1 апреля"   , callback_data="odate1")
            odate2   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="2 апреля"       , callback_data="odate2")
            odate3   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="3 апреля"       , callback_data="odate3")
            odate4       = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="4 апреля"   , callback_data="odate4")
            odate5   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="5 апреля"       , callback_data="odate5")
            odate6   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="6 апреля"       , callback_data="odate6")
            odate7       = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="7 апреля"   , callback_data="odate7")
            odate8   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="8 апреля"       , callback_data="odate8")
            odate9   = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="9 апреля"       , callback_data="odate9")
            keyboardorder.add(odate1, odate2, odate3)
            keyboardorder.add(odate4, odate5, odate6)
            keyboardorder.add(odate7, odate8, odate9)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выберите дату визита", reply_markup=keyboardorder)

#бесконечный цикл, что бы программа не завершалась
if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Я же вам [тут писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/800855/telegram-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/800886#800886) как правильно обрабатывать `callback`

Comment: я не совсем понял как это использовать, после каждой выпадающей менюшки писать 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'book')
#действие
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'callwaiter')
#действие
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'makeorder')
#действие , так?

Comment: На каждый коллбек своя функция